# Javascript class+call base class?

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this can be done in less lines and in a more clean way?

```
function BaseClass() {
  BaseClass.prototype.talk = function () {
    alert("I'm BaseClass");
  }
}

function MyClass() {
  BaseClass.call(this);
}
MyClass.prototype = new BaseClass();
MyClass.base = {};
MyClass.base.talk = MyClass.prototype.talk;
MyClass.prototype.talk = function () {
  alert("I'm MyClass");
  MyClass.base.talk();
}

var a = new MyClass();
a.talk();
```

Comment: Why are you declaring `BaseClass.prototype.talk` inside the constructor?

Comment: @JosephSilber: I don't know. Am I not suppose to do it there? Why wouldn't I declare it there?

Comment: Because then you're recreating the function every time you create a new object. The prototype is used to store functions that are shared between your objects.

Comment: @JosephSilber: Ah, so how would you rewrite all of this code?

Comment: You basically have it all figured out. I changed it around a tiny bit, and posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function BaseClass () {}

BaseClass.prototype.talk = function () {
    alert("I'm BaseClass");
}

function MyClass() {
    BaseClass.call(this);
}

MyClass.prototype = new BaseClass();
MyClass.base = BaseClass.prototype;

MyClass.prototype.talk = function () {
    alert("I'm MyClass");
    MyClass.base.talk.apply(this, arguments);
}

var a = new MyClass();
a.talk();
```

To make all this easier on yourself, don't re-invent the wheel. Look into John Resig's tiny inheritance library: [**Simple JavaScript Inheritance**](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/).

Comment: cool but the `talk.apply(this, arguments);` looks nasty

Comment: @acidzombie24 - Sure. Wish we didn't need it.